# Javascript when to show results

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

This is my Javascript below I want to show records on load and also show new records when added to the database

showrecords(); displays the records in the database where abouts can I put this in my code where it will work correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //showrecords()

    function showrecords()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "demo_show.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){

                $("#display").after(html);

                document.getElementById('content').value='';
                $("#flash").hide();

             }

        });
    }

    $(".comment_button").click(function() {

        var element = $(this);
        var test = $("#content").val();
        var dataString = 'content='+ test;

        if(test=='')
        {
            alert("Please Enter Some Text");

        }
        else
        {
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400)
                .html('<img src="http://tiggin.com/ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">Loading Comment...</span>');


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "demo_insert.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){


                    // $("#display").after(html);
                    document.getElementById('content').value='';
                    $("#flash").hide();

                    //Function for showing records
                    //showrecords();

                 }
            });
        }

    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is your code breaking? this is a bit vague...

Answer (score 0):

Though polluting the global namespace is not recommended. Here is what I would recommend for your code. Move the showRecords() out of Document ready function and refactor the update ajax code to another function 'updateRecords()'. Have only the event bindings inside the document ready function.

You could return the entire comments as response to POST 'demo_insert.php' service and call 'showRecords()' in the update service success callback.

Comment: what are the event bindings in this case.
Can you explain what you said abit more as I am abit of a javascript newbie

Thankyou
Pete

Answer (score 0):

i've pasted below (untested) code that i think should get the job done.  in order to call functions you've got to define them in an accessible area, whether in the "global" (can be called from anywhere) namespace as i've done below, or as part of an another object.

you also need to make sure your functions are defined before you try to call them, as everything works in a top down manner.

```
function showrecords() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "demo_show.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {

      $("#display").after(html);

      $('content').val('');
      $("#flash").hide();

    }

  });
}
function addComment() {
  var test = $("#content").val();
  var dataString = 'content=' + test;

  if (test == '') {
    alert("Please Enter Some Text");
  }
  else {
    $("#flash").show();
    $("#flash").fadeIn(400)
                .html('<img src="http://tiggin.com/ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">Loading Comment...</span>');

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "demo_insert.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function (html) {
        //$("#display").after(html);
        $('content').val('');
        $("#flash").hide();
        //Function for showing records
        showrecords();
      }
    });
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  showrecords()

  $(".comment_button").click(function () {
    addComment();
    return false;
  });
});
```